# Problemas com console.log no Snippet usando React

Tags: suporte, stack-snippets

Recentemente fiz perguntas que envolviam código em React e o `console.log` realizava o *log* no *console* do navegador, e não do Snippet, mesmo com a *checkbox* "Mostrar console" marcada.

Isso é um problema do próprio Snippet (algum tipo de conflito com os scripts do React) ou eu acabei formatando algo errado?

Exemplo breve:

```js
function Exemplo() {
  console.log("Um log que deveria aparecer no Snippet");

  return <div></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Exemplo /> , document.body);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente o que acontece é que o conteúdo padrão do `body` do Snippet é esse:

```html
<div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console"></div>
</div>
```

Ou seja, existem `div`'s responsáveis por exibir as mensagens do *console*.

Ao utilizar `ReactDOM.render(<Exemplo /> , document.body);`, o React substitui tudo o que há no `document.body`, removendo as `div`'s mencionadas acima.

Para resolver, basta criar um elemento no HTML do Snippet e então renderizar o componente nesse elemento:

```js
function Exemplo() {
  console.log("Um log que aparece no Snippet");

  return <div></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Exemplo />, document.querySelector("#container"));
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```